# Помогите встроить еще один запрос

Tags: sql

Вот в этот запрос

```
SELECT c.category_id, 
       cd.NAME, 
       c.image, 
       (SELECT Count(DISTINCT p.product_id) 
        FROM   oc_category_path cp 
               LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c 
                      ON ( cp.category_id = p2c.category_id ) 
               LEFT JOIN oc_product p 
                      ON ( p2c.product_id = p.product_id ) 
               LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s 
                      ON ( p.product_id = p2s.product_id ) 
        WHERE  cp.path_id = c.category_id 
               AND p.status = '1' 
               AND p.date_available <= Now() 
               AND p2s.store_id = '0') AS total_products 
FROM   oc_category c 
       LEFT JOIN oc_category_description cd 
              ON ( c.category_id = cd.category_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN oc_category_to_store c2s 
              ON ( c.category_id = c2s.category_id ) 
WHERE  c.parent_id = '0' 
       AND cd.language_id = '2' 
       AND c2s.store_id = '0' 
       AND c.status = '1' 
ORDER  BY c.sort_order, 
          Lcase(cd.NAME)
```

Нужно добавить еще один, который будет получать `description` из таблицы `oc_category_description`, где `category_id` равен `c.category_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я могу ошибиться, но по моему достаточно просто добавить в перечисление полей `cd.description` джоин по нужным полям у вас вроде бы и так уже делается.

Comment: Спасибо! Я де бестолочь... Не мог нормально посмотреть....